# How can I protect my client-side code with e.g. a license key?

Tags: javascript

There are some client-side libraries out there (for example the https://www.froala.com/wysiwyg-editor) which need to be activated with a license key. If no key was provided, there is a label "Unlicensed edition". How is such a protection implemented on a client-side library whose code is considered public? Any ideas on how to implement such a feature in my own libary?

Comment: Well, I imagineyou could do it by calling home. So if you "activate" the product, it will call home with the API key and return you the code that is considered "full version", if you haven't activated, it will just give you the free version code. In both cases it'd rely on fetching resources from somewhere. Which means that nobody would really "own" your product and you're entering SaaS territory. Which, on the other hand, isn't really that popular with client-side JS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing you can do to absolutely protect client side code (it is, after all, "client-side" code). You can obfuscate it and minify it to the point where it is unrecognizable. But a determined and skilled programmer CAN de-obfuscate it and gain access to the logic.

Libraries, like the one you mention simply bury the code that produces any watermarks or disclaimers, but that code is all yours for the looking.